# Stack Overflow Error when writing log by using log4j

Tags: log4j

I'm using log4j for writing log when running test automation.

Here is my method to write log:

```
public class Log {

private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName()); 

public static void info(String message)
{
    Log.info(message);
}
```

}
But whenever I use it, the stack overflow error is thrown like below:

Calling method:

```
Log.info("Click action is performed on My Account link");
```

Error:
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at helpers.Log.info(Log.java:21)
            at helpers.Log.info(Log.java:21)
            at helpers.Log.info(Log.java:21)
            at helpers.Log.info(Log.java:21)

Can anyone please help?

Comment: where is helpers class?

Comment: `public class Log {

 private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName()); 
 
  public static void info(String message)
 {
  Log.info(message);
 }

}`
This is full class.

Comment: Is there anyone can help out?

Comment: You are calling info method recursively. change your Log variable to logger and use logger.info